# Close SocketChannel ungracefully on purpose

Tags: java, socketchannel

Is it possible to close the `SocketChannel` without sending an end of stream message?

I want to free the socket resource from an application A but without the other side (application B) noticing it has ended, just as it would happen if A's computer suddenly disconnected from power source.
Obviously, B would notice it with socket keepalives eventually, but I don't want it to notice it by the end of stream message.

Comment: what happens if you get the associated socket through `SocketChannel.socket()` and close the socket?

Comment: According to the documentation of `Socket.close()` _"If this socket has an associated channel then the channel is closed as well."_ And a test confirms that end of stream is sent.